# llama index vectorstore querying with specific filtering

Tags: python, embedding, large-language-model, llama-index, chromadb

I have this simple code to query from files thats saved in a chroma vector store. Now if each file belongs to some user and each user can only query with data from their files and not others, how can I achieve this? I was thinking maybe save userId as metadata for each document and query with userId as filter, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
chroma_client = chromadb.PersistentClient(path="chroma")
chroma_collection = chroma_client.get_collection("quickstart")

vector_store = ChromaVectorStore(chroma_collection=chroma_collection)
index = VectorStoreIndex.from_vector_store(vector_store=vector_store)

retriever = index.as_retriever(retriever_mode='embedding')
query_engine = RetrieverQueryEngine(retriever)
query_engine = index.as_query_engine()
response = query_engine.query("what's the persons name")
print(response)
```

I tried asking the assistant from their website but it just gives random answers. Currently going through their doc to maybe get some lead.

Answer (score -1):

You can save the userId as metadata for each document and query with userId as filter :

```py
from langchain.embeddings.openai import OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain.vectorstores import Chroma

embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings()
db = Chroma.from_documents(docs, embeddings, persist_directory='db')
db.persist()

# Get all documents I've just stored in the Chroma database with metadata
docs_with_metadata = db.get()
```

And then filter the documents by userId using `pandas`:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(docs_with_metadata)
df[df['metadata']['userId'] == 'someUserId']
```

Comment: this solution filters results based on userId after the vector search is done. Ideally one would need ability to 1st filter documents based on metadata and then do vector search over it

Answer (score -2):

After messing around a bit, I found using metadata to tell the documents apart did not give consistent results so I created a vectorstore for each user and store their data there, working fine so far.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).